# Passing value on button click from google script file to sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to pass a list containing the start cell and the end cell of the active range, and putting each of the values in a input field.

```js
document.getElementById("btn-get-range").addEventListener('click', function(){
  google.script.run.withSuccesHandler(showValues).getSelectedRange();
});
  
function showValues(startEndList){
  document.getElementById('input-start-cell').value = startEndList[0];
  document.getElementById('input-end-cell').value = startEndList[1];
}

/* Google Script Code */

let UI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
let SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

function onOpen() {
   UI.createMenu('Get Range In Input')
      .addItem('Show Sidebar', 'showSidebar')
   .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar(){
   let html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar')
      .setTitle('Get Range In Input');
   UI.showSidebar(html);
}


function getSelectedRange() {
   let range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
   let startEndList = range.split(':');
  
   return startEndList
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center"> 
  <input id='input-start-cell' type='text' class="m-2">
  <input id='input-end-cell' type='text' class="m-2">
      
  <button id='btn-get-range' type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-50" class="m-2">Get Range</button>
</div>
```

Why is it not working?
Thx for yout time.

Comment: You may be adding the event listener before the dom has loaded.  Try hard wireing to the onClick in the tag or use window.onload or JQuery and $(function(){});

Comment: In your script, there is a spelling mistake for `withSuccesHandler`. Please modify `withSuccesHandler` to `withSuccessHandler`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)) I think that by this modification, your script works.

Comment: Thx Tanaike, I changed  `withSuccesHandler` to `withSuccessHandler` and it worked. I spent 2 hours trying to find my mistake. Thank u!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake for `withSuccesHandler`. Modify `withSuccesHandler` to `withSuccessHandler`.

So this:

```
document.getElementById("btn-get-range").addEventListener('click', function(){
  google.script.run.withSuccesHandler(showValues).getSelectedRange();
});
  
function showValues(startEndList){
  document.getElementById('input-start-cell').value = startEndList[0];
  document.getElementById('input-end-cell').value = startEndList[1];
}
```

Should be:

```
document.getElementById("btn-get-range").addEventListener('click', function(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showValues).getSelectedRange();
});
  
function showValues(startEndList){
  document.getElementById('input-start-cell').value = startEndList[0];
  document.getElementById('input-end-cell').value = startEndList[1];
}
```